# WasapiLoopbackCapture.DataAvailable reading silence bytes

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to record the speaker sound to a wave file using NAudio's WasapiLoopbackCapture by writing the stream of bytes available. The WasapiLoopbackCapture.DataAvailable **BytesRecorded** will be 0 is there is no sound. however in my case i am getting bytecount in **BytesRecorded** even though the speakers are silent. could you please let me know whats wrong here.

```
class CallResponse
{
    private WaveFileWriter _writer;
    private WasapiLoopbackCapture _waveIn;
    private string _inFile;
    private string _inFileCompressed;
    private int _duration;
    public bool _isRecording;
    public bool _speechDetected;

    public CallResponse()
    {
        _inFile = @"C:\Naresh\test.wav";
        _inFileCompressed = @"C:\Naresh\test16Hz.wav";
        _waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

        _waveIn.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.BytesRecorded);
            _writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            if (_writer.Position > _waveIn.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * _duration)
            {
                Console.Write("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bRecording stopped...");
                _waveIn.StopRecording();
            }
        };

        _waveIn.RecordingStopped += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (_writer != null)
            {
                _writer.Close();
                _writer.Dispose();
                _writer = null;
            }
            Console.Write("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bCompressing Audio...");
            using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(_inFile))
            {
                var resampler = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(reader, 16000);
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(_inFileCompressed, resampler);
            }
            _isRecording = false;
        };
    }

    public void DisposeObjects()
    {

        if (_waveIn != null)
        {
            _waveIn.Dispose();
            _waveIn = null;
        }
    }

    public void StartRecording(int duration = 5)
    {
        _writer = new WaveFileWriter(_inFile, _waveIn.WaveFormat);
        this._duration = duration;
        _speechDetected = false;
        _isRecording = true;
        Console.WriteLine("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bRecording....");
        _waveIn.StartRecording();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if something is playing audio, then `WasapiLoopbackCapture` will capture that audio, even if it contains silence. So there's nothing particularly wrong or surprising that you are getting non-zero `BytesRecorded` values. In fact, if no applications are sending audio to the device being captured, then what typically happens is that you won't get any `DataAvailable` callbacks at all.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Well my understanding was that the **DataAvailable** will be called async as soon as StartRecording is called irrespective of weather sound is available or not however the **BytesRecorded** would be **0** in case of silence.  Thanks for clarifying. This poses my next question, how can i detect silence from the sound, basically i want to start recording the moment i start receiving sound and skip all the initial silence bytes. **WaveFormat** being 48000 samples, 32 Bits/Sample, 2 channels. A quick reference to links or code would be very helpful.

Comment: Some more information of my problem, whey i play a pure music (with out any background noise) i see that the buffer contains non-zero value and when i pause the music the buffer contains usually zeros. But the sound bytes i am trying to read is from an IVR (Interactive Voice Response), and i am getting non zero values even when the IVR pauses for a while. There is absolutely now why i can detect the change in the bytes stream when there is silence Vs the IVR is speaking. Could you please help me here.

Comment: I tried all sort of things to detect when IVR is speaking Vs when it is silent.

Comment: Silence detection usually involves examining the value of each sample, so you'd use something like `BitConverter` to read all the floating point samples out of the recorded buffer.

Comment: Thanks you Mark. this helped me a lot.